# Plot 3 categorical variables with dependencies on previous column

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have the following data that i want to plot using r (ggplot2 or any other package)

QUESTION IS: What is the best method to visualize in R,  to understand the relationship between those who are Happy = Yes, Pay = No and Donate = Yes (and other combinations).

```
AreYouHappy | WouldYouPay | WouldYouDonate

Yes | No  | Yes

Yes | No  | No

Yes | No  | Yes

Yes | Yes | Yes

Yes | No  | No

No  | Yes | Yes

Yes | No  | No

Yes | No  | Yes

...[58 data points]
```

[Reproducible code]

```
df <- data.frame(
  cbind(AreYouHappy = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.75,.25)),
        WouldYouPay = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.25,.75)),
        WouldYouDonate = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.50,.50))))
```

I tried VennDiagram, SankeyDiagram, Bar, Mosiac Plot, using ggplot2/plotluck but I can't get a handle on any of them. I've tried using reshape2, but i can't understand how to change these data point into a matrix of count and then plot it. I searched all over. Please do help-- where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is a question on *CrossValidated* concerning the visualisation of 3 categorical variables that might help you (8 answers):  [link to the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148554/how-can-you-visualize-the-relationship-between-3-categorical-variables)

Answer (score 3):

If it's dataset concerning happiness then why not to use `upset` :-)

```
# Data
df <- data.frame( cbind(AreYouHappy = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.75,.25)), WouldYouPay = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.25,.75)), WouldYouDonate = sample( c("Yes", "No"), 58, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.50,.50))))
# Transform original data into 0 and 1
df01 <- apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x == "Yes", 1, 0))

# Plot using UpSetR
library(UpSetR)
upset(data.frame(df01))
```

[image]

More about UpSetR [in the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/README.html).

Comment: @thedancingqueen is there any way I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(WouldYouPay)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = WouldYouDonate)) +
   facet_wrap(~AreYouHappy, labeller = "label_both")
```

Comment: It works. I was hoping for a more intuitive vizualization. Any thoughts on that? I wonder if i am complicating it beyond need :)